# Calc 3 - "Circulation" and Flux Question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Let F(x,y)=⟨1,−xy⟩ and C be the unit circle centered at the origin drawn in a counterclockwise fashion as t runs from 0 to 2π. Set up an integral that will compute the flow along a curve C (circulation) and an integral that will compute the flow across a curve C (flux).

I'm confused on what is meant by "circulation"... is this interchangeable with scalar curl? 
Also, it should be given in this format for "circulation": 
∮F∙dp (across C) = ∮(____)dt from **_ to _**
and in this format for flux:
∮F∙dn (across C) = ∮(____)dt from **_ to _**

What is p? What is n?

I figured that the limits for both are 0 to 2pi, but I don't understand what to put inside the actual integral for either, especially circulation. For flux, I tried just putting in the divergence of F (by the Divergence Theorem) but that didn't work because it's in terms of dt and not dV.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is a simple, oriented, closed curve in the plane with unit tangent field $\mathbf{T}$ and outward unit normal vector field $\mathbf{n}$, and $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field on $C$, the circulation of $\mathbf{F}$ around $C$ is the integral
$$
    \int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{T}\,ds = \int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}
$$
The circulation is related to the scalar curl by Green's theorem.

The flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across $C$ is the integral
$$
    \int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,ds
$$
The flux is related to the divergence by Gauss's theorem.